# Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have a report where I have several static rows, each row has it own filters and group, the field `Prem` is calculated based on the filters set for each row group.
I need to summarize all the rows into one total:

```
=ReportItems!TextBox248.Value + ReportItems!TextBox249.Value + ReportItems!TextBox250.Value + 
 ReportItems!TextBox251.Value + ReportItems!TextBox252.Value + ReportItems!TextBox253.Value + 
 ReportItems!TextBox254.Value
```

However, I get this error when I run the report:

> The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox267’ refers to the
>   report item ‘TextBox248’.  Report item expressions can only refer to
>   other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing
>   grouping scope. Letters in the names of report items must use the
>   correct case.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple solution here really, but SSRS is case-sensitive.  Looks like your expression uses `TextBox` when the names of the textboxes are actually `Textbox`. So simply, you should use this expression.

```
=ReportItems!Textbox248.Value + ReportItems!Textbox249.Value + ReportItems!Textbox250.Value + 
 ReportItems!Textbox251.Value + ReportItems!Textbox252.Value + ReportItems!Textbox253.Value + 
 ReportItems!Textbox254.Value
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even when used case-sensitive names for textboxes.